# Update Quartz.net jobs and triggers from XML

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am trying to move my Quartz.NET setup from RamJobStore to AdoJobStore to deal with situations when the server is down for some reason when a trigger should fire.

I use the XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin for job and trigger initialization. The database connection is working and at application startup the jobs and triggers are inserted in the database tables.

```
<processing-directives>
   <overwrite-existing-data>true</overwrite-existing-data>
   <ignore-duplicates>false</ignore-duplicates>
</processing-directives>
```

If I set the overwrite-existing-data property to true in the XML config, all saved data is overwritten (for example PREV_FIRE_TIME, NEXT_FIRE_TIME, START_TIME for triggers) at the next application startup. If I set the property to false, changes for example in trigger cron expressions are ignored.

Is there a way to just "update" the data from XML?